# How to order all values in group_concat ?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case, group-concat

**Query:-**

```
SELECT emp.emp_id AS employeeId,
       emp.emp_name AS employeeName,
       **group_concat(CASE
                          WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time
                          ELSE ''
                      END) AS logTimings**,
                                         shift AS shift
FROM at_hr_logs_Jan l,
     at_hr_emp employee,
     at_dates dt
WHERE user_id=00000247
  AND l.user_id=emp.emp_code
  AND emp.dept_id=1
  AND l.status_id=fn_getcodevalue_id('STS', 'ACTIVE')
  AND l.log_date=dt.att_date
GROUP BY l.log_date ;
```

**Actual oupput:-**

```
Employee Id  Employee Name Log Timings

00000247  M. Rama Rao  18:03,17:40,13:35,11:48,09:19

00000247  M. Rama Rao  15:24,09:11,18:44,16:37,15:27,15:24
```

But need:

```
Employee Id  Employee Name Log Timings

00000247  M. Rama Rao  09:19,11:48,13:35,17:40,18:03

00000247  M. Rama Rao  09:11,15:27,15:24,15:24,16:37,18:44
```

Comment: did you tried with `order by l.log_date `

Comment: `CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE 
'' END` what is the point ?? it will always true

Comment: yes..I was tried then it shows log_date order by but it not effect internal values

Comment: @Ravi..CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time order by  ELSE null  END..any possibility for this??

Comment: Please post your table structure and sample data.

Comment: @SimhachalamSopeti I don't know what you understand with `WHEN log_date = log_date` it is always `true` so, you will never get into `ELSE`. It is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ORDER BY` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT`.

I don't understand the logic  of `WHEN log_date = log_date`, it will always be `true`. Then, there is no point of having `CASE` statement and it **won't** fall into `ELSE` case.

```
 group_concat(CASE WHEN log_date = log_date THEN log_time ELSE '' END)
```

**and**

```
group_concat(log_time)
```

Both will give you same result. So, you should do following changes

```
group_concat(log_time ORDER BY log_time) AS logTimings
```

Comment: @SimhachalamSopeti You should read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235. I can see, you have never accepted any answers. Make sure you have a habit of accepting correct answer when you post any question.  Remember, people put their time to solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Your are aggregating by `log_date`, so the `case` *EXPRESSION* is not needed in the `group_concat()`.
- The best practice is to put all non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.
- I would recommend including the date and shift in the `SELECT` as well.
- The table alias for the `at_hr_emp` is `employee` (in your code) but it is referenced as `emp`.  Just use the abbreviation `e`.

Hence, this query should be written as:

```
SELECT e.emp_id AS employeeId, e.emp_name AS employeeName, l.log_date,
       group_concat(log_time order by log_time) as logTimings,
       shift AS shift
FROM at_hr_logs_Jan l JOIN
     at_hr_emp e
     ON l.user_id = e.emp_code JOIN
     at_dates dt
     ON l.log_date = dt.att_date
WHERE e.user_id=00000247 AND e.dept_id = 1 AND
      l.status_id = fn_getcodevalue_id('STS', 'ACTIVE')
GROUP BY e.emp_id, e.emp_name, l.log_date, shift;
```